# What is an "infiltration map"?

Tags: maps

I came by an "[infiltration map](https://www.google.com/search?q=map%20carpathian%20mountains&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7s7Cvy7XfAhVno4sKHWxTCjcQ_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=943#imgrc=G1FndkMe_2_BVM:)" today.

But I cannot find any definition of this on Wikipedia or the web.

What is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infiltration map is the map of the proportion of water that would infiltrate into the soil in case of rain. During a rain event, you can neglect the amount of water that evaporate, so the water that does not infiltrate (go into the soil, feeding the aquifers) will either accumulate (flood) or run of (causing erosion and, possibly, floods lower in the valley). Large values of infiltration are therefore welcome.

The main factor that influence the infiltration are the slope, the land cover and the soil types.

Answer (score -1):

Infiltration is a part of water balance. You can see definition in the article of Wikipedia Infiltration (hydrology).